# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.odysseus.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, juel

My application is using apache camel along with spring.
I am getting exception in EL expression shown below in camel-context.xml
in.body is request object and it has method getParam().

```
<filter>
    <el>${(in.body.getParam != null) and (in.body.getParam[validate] == 'Y')}</el>
    <log message="validating...${in.body.getParam[errorResponse]}" />
    <filter>
        <method ref="validationExecutor" method="execute" ></method>
        <setBody><simple>${in.body.getParam[errorResponse]}</simple></setBody>
        <stop />
    </filter>
</filter>
```

I have added dependency as

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-juel</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```

still i'm getting exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.odysseus.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl

i have further looked into classes loaded by  using vm arg -verbose:class I found that there are other jars loaded which are related to EL

```
apache-tomcat-7.0.62/lib/el-api.jar
geronimo-el_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar
```

I have not specified them in pom, but still these jars got added.
how can i remove them?

Comment: You can try with simple

<simple>${body.getParam[validate]} == 'Y'</simple>

Comment: but sometimes body doesn't contain request object , thats why i want to add extra check for ${in.body.getParam} != null

Comment: The simple language deals with that if the header does not exist then the predicate does not match.

Comment: no it is throwing exception as it doesn't get getParam from body object

Comment: Ah okay use the null safe operation `?.`, eg body`?.getParam`

Comment: I can't remember if you need camel-script as well to be able to use additional languages (other than Simple).
Maybe try adding:
`<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-script</artifactId>
  <version>x.x.x</version>
</dependency>`